# How to make Zookeeper in HDP serve the IPs of the master/gateway instead of hostnames

Tags: hbase, apache-zookeeper, hdp

I have a situation where in the HBase client is running on a cloud where it cannot resolve the hostname of the HDP master/gateway. I have replaced all hostnames with IPs in the hbase site xml that is configured on the client side. However, when establishing the connection to HBase, the client is throwing a unknown host exception for the HDP gateway hostname. My understanding is that the client has received the hostname of the gateway from the zookeeper on the HDP. So the question is, is there a way to make zookeeper return the IP addresses of the master and gateway instead of the hostname.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

i couldt understant your question but if you put all ip/host information to your /etc/hosts file on each server it might resolve the problem.